# Vector of dictionaries of different types in julia 0.6

Tags: dictionary, julia

I am a bit confused about the new `where` syntax in julia 0.6.
I have something like this:

```
a=Dict(["a"=>"b"])
b=Dict(["a"=>3])
c=Dict(["a"=>"c"])
```

I want a function that receive a vector of dictionaries without having to make an explicit conversion.
I tried with:

```
function bbb(a::Vector{Dict{String, Any}})
     println(a)
end
```

And it didn't work.

Then I tried with

```
function bbb(a::Vector{Dict{String, T} where T})
     println(a)
end
bbb([a,b])   #Works
bbb([a,c])   #Fails
bbb([a,b,c]) #Works
```

I have overloaded bbb with every combination that I can recieve in order to make an explicit conversion. But I'm still wondering how is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is invariance in action.  It's a complicated case since there are two levels of parameterization, but the principle is the same.

- `Dict{String, Any}` describes a dictionary where the keys are strings and the value type is exactly `Any`.  Parametric invariance means that `Dict{String, Int}` is *not* a subtype of `Dict{String, Any}`.
- `Dict{String, T} where T` describes all dictionaries with string keys. The type var `T` can match any type, including `Any` or `Int`.

Now, when you start talking about a vector of dictionaries, the same principle applies:

- `Vector{Dict{String, T} where T}` describes a vector where the element type is *exactly* `Dict{String, T} where T`.  Parametric invariance means that `Vector{Dict{String, Int}}` is *not* a subtype of `Vector{Dict{String, T} where T}`.
- `Vector{D} where D <: (Dict{String, T} where T)` describes all vectors where the elements are dictionaries with string keys.  The type var `D` can match any dictionary type where the keys are strings, including `Dict{String, T} where T` or `Dict{String, Int}`.

You can express this much more simply with the shorthand notation:

```
function bbb(a::Vector{<: Dict{String, <: Any}})
     println(a)
end
```

Comment: Indeed!. Thank you.