# Why doesn't Julia's Dict{String, Any} accept 'any' value

Tags: dictionary, parameters, julia

I wrote a function that should take a `Dict{String, <anything>}` (so with any value). However when I specify the required parameter as `Dict{String, Any}` the function only takes the explicit `Dict{String, Any}`. Is there a way to let a `Dict` take any value?

```
function funky(arg::Dict{String, Any})
    return "Oh, hi mark."
end
```

```
julia> funky(Dict("Oh" => [0 1; 2 3]))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching funky(::Dict{String,Array{Int64,2}})
Closest candidates are:
  funky(::Dict{String,Any})

julia> funky(Dict{String, Any}("Oh" => [0 1; 2 3]))
"Oh, hi mark."
```

Comment: This is parametric invariance; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219387/vector-of-dictionaries-of-different-types-in-julia-0-6/45220902#45220902 for example.  `Dict("Oh" => [0 1; 2 3])` doesn't create a `Dict{String, Any}`, it creates a `Dict{String, Array{Int,2}}`.

Comment: Is there a fundamental difference between `function funky(arg::Dict{String, T}) where T` and `function funky(arg::Dict{String, T} where T)`. Or is it just that you could do something like this `function funky(arg1::Dict{String, T}, arg2::Dict{String, T}) where T`?

Comment: For one argument, no, the only difference is that `T` becomes available for use in the function body if you use that very first form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write it as in your first version of funky, the function does not expect any type but exactly type `Any`, whereas in the following definition,

```
julia> function funky(arg::Dict{String, <:Any})
  return "Oh, hi mark."
end

julia> funky(Dict("Oh" => [0 1; 2 3]))
"Oh, hi mark."
```

any subtype of `Any` is accepted (so all types), which is due to the subtype operator `<:`. You did this implicitly in your second version. So to wrap it up the main difference is:

```
julia> typeof([0 1; 2 3]) == Any # first verion
false

julia> typeof([0 1; 2 3]) <: Any # second version
true
```

Comment: Oeh, I probably like your solution more than what I did.

Comment: You can also call this `arg::Dict{String}` and leave off the second type parameter.

Comment: I accepted this answer. But there are many good and useful answers in the comments of this and other answers as well. So maybe I'll accept another answer in the future if somebody decides to write a nice recap of all the options.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution.

```
function funky(arg::Dict{String, T}) where T
    return "Oh, hi mark."
end
```

Which [according to the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#where) is just syntactic sugar for:

```
function funky(arg::Dict{String, T}) where T <: Any
    return "Oh, hi mark."
end
```

```
julia> funki(Dict("Oh" => [0 1; 2 3]))
"Oh, hi mark."
```

However, I still don't fully understand why `Dict{String, Any}` shouldn't work either. Maybe somebody with more knowledge could explain.